# Properly close a SQL connection in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-connection

I have a pretty complex SQL query which can't be done, or can't be done easily, in ActiveRecord.

I created my SQL query and did this:

```
sql = getcomplexsqlquery
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

and loop through the result.

How do I make sure that the SQL connection gets closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't try to close it.

You are using ActiveRecord's connection to your database, which is the same one it would use for its normal queries.

Closing one would close the other, leaving one angry ActiveRecord and Rails as a result.

Comment: It is advisable to free the `result` though. Ref: http://www.fngtps.com/2008/free-result-after-using-activerecord-base-connection-execute/

Comment: That comment is from 2008 which is pretty stale. I'd hope by now that freeing the result should happen once it falls out of scope and gets garbage collected.

Comment: So even if that sql execution fails, the connection will still be closed? So, no need to put in a begin/rescue/ensure block?

Comment: There is a difference between a query and a connection. The connection should be maintained whether a query fails or succeeds. That is the conduit used by ActiveRecord to talk to the database. A query is simply a question (or statement) sent to the database, that waits for a response of some sort, and is sent through that connection. Closing the connection would be bad. A query will "end" immediately if there is an error, but the connection will be maintained, and you shouldn't try to force it closed otherwise you'll have to reopen it to do further queries.

Comment: Thanks. I'm from the .NET/SQL world and you have to ensure you close connections to avoid draining the connection pool.